# Android update - perform database actions

Tags: android, sqlite

I don't exactly know how android updates the applications. As far as I've read around here it keeps the SQLite database. So, imagine this scenario: one application that uses SQLite database for persisting data. After a while I release v2 which contains some database changes and I need to update user data in database. How can I make this during the update process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29). Subclass the SQLiteOpenHelper class and do all the stuff to update the tables in the onUpgrade method.

As you will see, the constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper takes as last parameter the Database version:

> version: number of the database (starting at 1); if the database is older, onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) will be used to upgrade the database

Comment: If I release a new version of the app, the SQLite database also changes automatically ?

Comment: You'll need to pass to the constructor a version number greater than the one you passed before (you can for instance keep that DB version in a constant of your SQLiteOpenHelper subclass or wrapper). Then the call to onUpgrade will be made automatically.